# How can I change the style of the content of an iFrame with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use an iFrame to display an HTML webpage from an external source but, I can't get it to work with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that (the browser won't let you, for security reason). If the external content of the iFrame is from the same server as the root page, then you can use javascript but no css from the root html.